# Iterating with the subreport parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

I have place a subreport in my master report. I have my query like, for a application I have some 3 `jobID`. Based on this `jobID` I need to fetch the related data. I placed the `jobID` in the detail band and passed the same to the subreport as parameter.

Since the subreport is reporting only once in the master report, even though I have 3 `jobID`, it is display the first `jobID` data in the master report.

I need to get data for all the `jobID` of a application.

Comment: In which band of the master report have you put the subreport? It has to be in the detail band in order to be repeated for all you data.

Answer (score 0):

please see whether your sub report shows value for 3id if not then it cant appear data from three reports.
also place the subreport on the details band.

simple query with tree id returnce three row in the sub report is must. then only it will apear in the main report.

Note : if you place the report on the non repeating band. then that band only show the first comming data insted of showing 3 lines.

donot place sub report on title/pageheader/column heder with repeting value.

place only those sub report on this band which give only one value or one row